# How do I access the $ref in the JSON recursively as to complete the whole JSON?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this schema, which has `$ref` in it. I need to recursively (assuming there are no infinite cycles) fill in references. That is, wherever `$ref` is present, the whole object is replaced with what it points.

Note, I can't use any libraries and need to write the Class/function on my own. I did see [jsonref](https://github.com/gazpachoking/jsonref/blob/master/jsonref.py) but was unable to understand the LazyLoad and the callbacks.

Could it be done in a simpler way? I've been trying to do this for days.

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "pet": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name":  { "type": "string" },
        "breed": { "type": "string" },
        "age":  { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["name", "breed", "age"]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "cat": { "$ref": "#/definitions/pet" },
    "dog": { "$ref": "#/definitions/pet" }
  }
}
```

becomes,

```
{
  "definitions": {
    "pet": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "breed": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "breed",
        "age"
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "cat": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "breed": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "breed",
        "age"
      ]
    },
    "dog": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "breed": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
          "type": "string"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "name",
        "breed",
        "age"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

This is the JSON I'm trying to solve, thanks.

```
{
  "$id": "https://example.com/nested-schema.json",
  "title": "nested-schema",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "required": [
    "Music",
    "MusicID",
    "Composer"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "MusicID": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 0,
      "maxLength": 0
    },
    "Music": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Music"
    },
    "Composer": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 0
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Music": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "Date"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "Artist": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/AlbumInformation"
        }
      }
    },
    "AlbumInformation": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "Name"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Name": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "description": "nested-schema"
}
```

Help will be deeply appreciated, thanks.

Some code that I have been trying:

```
@classmethod
def replace_refs(cls, obj, _recursive=False, **kwargs):
    kwargs["_recursive"] = True
    path = list(kwargs.pop("_path", ()))
    if isinstance(obj, Mapping):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                if '$ref' in v:
                    import pdb
                    print(k, v)
            cls.replace_refs(v)
    return obj
```

Comment: You mean that you can't use external modules or you can't use python's built-in json module either? Is this homework? Where is your current code?

Comment: I can use json module but not json-ref. I've updated the current code, it's incomplete though. When recursively doing it and I get $ref, how do I detach the $ref and insert the JSON it's pointing to?

Comment: `v['$ref'] = my_new_data_structure`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is only needed to crawl the document. Actually resolving the ref can be done iteratively. Resolving cycles is left as an exercise to the student.

```
import json

obj = {
  "$id": "https://example.com/nested-schema.json",
  "title": "nested-schema",
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "required": [
    "Music",
    "MusicID",
    "Composer"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "MusicID": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 0,
      "maxLength": 0
    },
    "Music": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/Music"
    },
    "Composer": {
      "type": "integer",
      "minimum": 0,
      "maximum": 0
    }
  },
  "definitions": {
    "Music": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "Date"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Date": {
          "type": "string",
          "format": "date"
        },
        "Artist": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/AlbumInformation"
        }
      }
    },
    "AlbumInformation": {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "Name"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "Name": {
          "type": "string",
          "minLength": 5
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "description": "nested-schema"
}

def resolveRef(ref):
  refpath = ref["$ref"].split("/")[1:]
  refobj = obj
  for node in refpath:
    refobj = refobj[node]
  resolveRefs(refobj)
  return refobj

def resolveRefs(j):
  for k,v in j.items():
    if type(v) == dict and "$ref" in v:
      j[k] = resolveRef(v)
    elif type(v) == dict:
      resolveRefs(j[k])

resolveRefs(obj)
print(json.dumps(obj, indent=4))
```

Example: https://repl.it/repls/WarmKnottySupport

Comment: I was trying to do recursive if it is nested. Can I paste a scenario where this fails?

Comment: Edited my answer.